# How do I block Tor on Linux?

Tags: debian, nftables, tor

I want to block Tor Browser on a Linux computer (Debian 10).

Being more specific: I want to block local users from launching Tor browser on this machine.

There is a single user account on the system and that user doesn't have root access (only I do).

It is not possible to just uninstall Tor Browser since the user can download a release and run it (even without root access).

The reason I want to achieve that is: I'm using dnsmasq on that computer to allow only whitelisted domain names. But using Tor can circumvent that.

I tried running this script as root:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true; do
    for i in "[T|t]or [B|b]rowser" "[F|f]irefox"; do
        pkill -f "$i"
    done
    sleep 5
done
```

But it isn't reliable. The user can just change some binary files names and Tor will launch.

Internet searches suggested the possibility of using nftables to block Tor, but there is not a ton of material available and I don't know if it is really feasible.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. Do you mean you are running a webserver and you don't want users to access it with the Tor browser? Or do you want to block your _local_ users from launching Tor browser on this machine? If the latter, why don't you just uninstall Tor Browser? Is this a multi-user system? Are you the admin? Do other users have root access? We need to know all this.

Comment: Thank you. If there's still anything missing, please let me know.

Comment: What is the computer used for? It is feasible to prevent users from installing any software (e.g. run it like a kiosk)? What about using a restricted shell (see `man bash`, look for `RESTRICTED SHELL`)? What if instead of using `dnsmasq` to whitelist domains you set up a filtering proxy on a second system (this in combination with restricted firewall rules would let you do what you want)?

Comment: What about mounting home directories (and maybe `/tmp` and other world-writable directories) with the `noexec` flag? This would largely prevent people from installing new software.

Comment: The computer is used by a tech savvy child to study, browse etc. I'd prefer to prevent him only from executing the Tor Browser, but I'm willing to go for blocking all software installation if that is what's necessary. I must say the kid agrees he needs control. So a kiosk is a viable option if that is what it takes. Following your suggestions, I've read about `restricted shell`, but mounting home and world-writable directories with the `noexec` flag solved the problem for now (with the cost of him not being able to install anything). So thank you @larsks!

Comment: I only use `dnsmasq` because I've found it simple to set up. But it seems that establishing a filtering proxy with firewall rules is a better solution -- because I'll be able to block tor connections without having to rely on a restrictive "noexec" policy. I feel I'm going to have to study a lot in order to set this up. Just a question: will I need a second computer to do that? Something like a Raspberry Pi? Right now I only have one computer at home. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved reliably, **if you are working with a *blocklist***. I mean, in your current setup, for instance, this person doesn't even need the Tor Browser. They might as well use plain old Firefox by changing the settings to do [DNS over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS). Then, what are you gonna do? Block TCP connections to destination port 443? If you somehow only block domains that are well-known DNS over HTTPS providers, you are just driving them to use obscure, and possibly dubious, providers which are going to log everything (to say the least). Not advisable.

However, if you are working with a carefully crafted list of domains and want to allow browsing those domains, and *only those domains*, then the following is a possible solution:

- install [sniproxy](https://github.com/dlundquist/sniproxy) on a machine in your network (can be a virtual machine)
- for the sniproxy configuration, populate the tables with your allowed domains
- put sniproxy to listen in the LAN on ports 80 and 443
- configure DNS to point to the IP address of the machine running sniproxy for all allowed domains and 0.0.0.0 (or localhost) for the rest
- with iptables/nftables, block any TCP connections from the target machine to destination port 443, except connections to the machine running sniproxy

I suppose, something similar can also be achieved with [squid](https://github.com/squid-cache/squid).